# how to push new element to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Here i have Array of objects, in this agents array has 0 elements. i have add an object to  this. `"agents": [{}]` in this i want to add below element:

```json
{
    "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agentteam/5020",
    "changeStamp": 18,
    "agentCount": 0,
    "description": "Cumulus All Team",
    "name": "CumulusAll",
    "peripheral": {
        "id": 5000,
        "name": "CUCM_PG_1"
    },
    "peripheralId": 5000,
    "supervisorCount": 0,
    "agents": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

I want to add below element to the above in agents array `"agents" [{}]`

```json
{
    "agent": [
        {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5101",
            "agentId": "1300",
            "firstName": "Sammy",
            "lastName": "Jackson",
            "userName": "cgjackson"
        },
        {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5106",
            "agentId": "1305",
            "firstName": "Angel",
            "lastName": "Jolie",
            "userName": "cgjolie"
        },
        {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5109",
            "agentId": "1308",
            "firstName": "Steve",
            "lastName": "O",
            "userName": "cgsteveo"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the final output i want to be achieved

```json
{
    "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agentteam/5016",
    "changeStamp": 201,
    "agentCount": 3,
    "description": "Cumulus Finance Team",
    "name": "CumulusFinance",
    "peripheral": {
        "id": 5000,
        "name": "CUCM_PG_1"
    },
    "peripheralId": 5000,
    "supervisorCount": 1,
    "agents": [
        {
            "agent": [
                {
                    "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5101",
                    "agentId": "1300",
                    "firstName": "Sammy",
                    "lastName": "Jackson",
                    "userName": "cgjackson"
                },
                {
                    "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5106",
                    "agentId": "1305",
                    "firstName": "Angel",
                    "lastName": "Jolie",
                    "userName": "cgjolie"
                },
                {
                    "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5109",
                    "agentId": "1308",
                    "firstName": "Steve",
                    "lastName": "O",
                    "userName": "cgsteveo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "supervisors": [
        {
            "supervisor": [
                {
                    "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5174",
                    "agentId": "1082",
                    "firstName": "Rick",
                    "lastName": "Barrows",
                    "userName": "rbarrows@dcloud.cisco.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you don't know how to use array.push https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: is the problem how to add an element to an array? did you just try `.push()`? anyway I'm not sure to understand but you have `.agent` as an array (contrary to what the singular name suggests) maybe you need to merge that array inside the `.agents` array? in that case also `obj.agents = [...obj.agents, ...obj2.agent]` would work. Anyway you should really make the question more clear

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you do not mean to push, but to replace agents[0] (plural) by the agent (singular) array, then Object.assign(agents[0], agent) might be what you are looking for. Please be more explicit in what you want to achieve.

Comment: BTW are you sure about the final output? It's weird to have `data.agents.agent` being an array.

Comment: `input.agents[0] = input2.agent`?

Comment: @RoboRobok, yes i copied final out from the working sample. i has to be like that only

Comment: What was wrong about my previous statement to use  Object.assign(agents[0], agent)?

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it via expression or side-effect. I'm going to name your object `oldObject` and your agents object `agentsObject`.

Expression:

```js
const newObject = {
    ...oldObject,
    agents: [ agentsObject ],
};
```

Side-effect:

```js
oldObject.agents = [ agentsObject ];
```

Comment: i tried side-effect method, it is not giving correct result, it is not adding agent label inside agents.

Comment: Did you name the variables correctly?

Comment: i posted how my final out put should look like

Comment: @GaneshPutta your question got deleted, but I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But here one thing is missng. Actually it should be like this "agents":[{"agent":[{..., but from your answer i got "agents":{"agent":[{... Everything is same, but missing "[" before agent, can u please take a look. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agentteam/5020","changeStamp":18,"agentCount":0,"description":"Cumulus All Team","name":"CumulusAll","peripheral":{"id":5000,"name":"CUCM_PG_1"},"peripheralId":5000,"supervisorCount":0,"agents":[{}]}

const obj1= {
"agent":[{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5101","agentId":"1300","firstName":"Sammy","lastName":"Jackson","userName":"cgjackson"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5106","agentId":"1305","firstName":"Angel","lastName":"Jolie","userName":"cgjolie"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5109","agentId":"1308","firstName":"Steve","lastName":"O","userName":"cgsteveo"}]
}

obj.agents.splice(0,1,obj1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

I replaced answer again, please check.

```
> Blockquote
```

Comment: This neither merges the 2 arrays nor replaces one with the other. This does a bit of both. If there are 4 items in `obj.agents` and 3 items in `obj1.agent`, it will replace the first 3 items in `obj.agents` with 3 items from `obj1.agent` and will keep the final item in `agents` as is.

Comment: @adiga, i tried but it is not giving the correct output. I added expected result in my question. can u please take a look

Comment: Please check my code again. At first, I misunderstood your code.